# wpf TabControl bindings

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a List of instances of some class. One of the properties of this class is TabItem. I want to bind this list to TabControl but I have no idea how to specify that TabItems are stored in this property.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear how you want your `TabControl` laid out but maybe this snippet will help.

```
    <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfInstances}">
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- This is the tab header -->
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabItem}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- This is the tab content -->
                <Grid>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabItem}" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```